# connection Angular-ElasticSearch

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch

I am a beginner in AngularJS, I have a problem with the connection ElasticSearch, I solved the data recovery problem ElasticSearch to nodejs, but I unable to retrieve data Angular Node to show it on my interface. I copied by internet codes but in vein, help me please!

Comment: show your efforts so far

Comment: in the controller i wrote this code: $scope.SendData=function(){

        $http.post('http://.......:9200')
             .success(function(data,status){
                $scope.PostDataResponse=data;
                console.log($scope.data);
                })
             .error(function(data,status){
                $scope.PostDataResponse=data;
            })

        }
 
$scope.SendData();

Comment: and i wrote a method: get   
        $scope.keyword = '';
        $scope.GetAllData = function () {
            $http.get('......:9200')
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.GetAllData = data;
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
               
            });
        };

        
$scope.GetAllData();